# How do i display the default value in a row if user has not yet filled in the row?

Tags: php

This is my html/php:

```
<span class="description-text">
    <h5 class="widget-user-desc">
        <?php echo $row['company_location'] ?>
    </h5>
</span>
```

And in my database i have set the default value to:User has not yet provided their location.
How do i then echo this default value when information has not yet been filled in by the user?

This was the final solution:

```
<?php if (empty($row['company_location'])) { echo "Not Provided";} else { echo $row['company_location'];}?>
```

Comment: you could use a ternary operator

Comment: how do i do that.Im new to php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php Look under "Ternary Operator", there's an example there. Or use an `if/else`.

Comment: ok,thanks.checking it out now

Comment: tenary operator doesn't exist. Closest matches: in this link you provided.

Comment: I tried this:<?php echo $row[$company_location?:'Location not set'] ?>but im getting an error-Undefined index: Location not set in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a conditional that checks if the row is set:

```
<span class="description-text">
  <h5 class="widget-user-desc">
    <?php echo isset($row['company_location']) ? $row['company_location'] : "User has not yet provided their location."; ?>
  </h5>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks.This worked...With a few modifications,this is how i did it <?php if (empty($row['company_location'])) {
                        echo "Not Provided";} 
                            else {
                        echo $row['company_location'];}?>

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
<?php if (empty($row['company_location'])) {
                    echo "Not Provided";} 
                        else {
                    echo $row['company_location'];}?>
```